# What video software is being used to display the animation of this video?

Tags: software-recommendation

The link is from kickstarter video:

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/biolite/biolite-baselantern-smartgrid-goes-off-grid?ref=category_featured

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the animation of the product, it could be cinema4d, blender or something similar. I bet it could be done in after effects as well.